# Right-continuity of a function

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, continuity

Let $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function.

1. Let $I \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that for every $x \in I$, the limit: $$\displaystyle\lim_{y \to x^+,y \in \mathbb{Q}}f(y)$$ exists in $\mathbb{R}.$ Prove that the function $h(x):=\lim_{y \to x^+,y \in \mathbb{Q}}f(y),x \in I,$ is right-continuous on $I.$
2. If for every $x \in \mathbb{Q},\lim_{y \to x^+,y \in \mathbb{Q}}f(y)$ exists in $\mathbb{R},$ then is it true that $h$ is right-continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Regarding 1. if $x \in I,\epsilon>0$ are fixed, then there exists $\delta>0$ such that for every $y \in \mathbb{Q} \cap]x,x+\delta[,|f(y)-h(x)| \leq \epsilon.$ So if $y \in ]x,x+\delta[,$ then $|h(y)-h(x)|=\lim_{r \to y^+,r \in \mathbb{Q}}|f(r)-h(x)| \leq \epsilon,$ which proves the right-continuity on $I$.

**Regarding 2., taking $I=\mathbb{Q}$ in part 1., we deduce that $h$ is right-continuous on $\mathbb{Q}.$ Can we conclude that $h$ is right-continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ using the density of $\mathbb{Q}$ ?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in 2) if you mean $\lim_{y \to x^+,y \in \mathbb{Q}}f(y)$ exists $x \in \mathbb{Q}$, then the answer is NO. Take $f(y)=0$ for $x$ rational and $f(x)=1$ for $x$ irrational.